# Using postgresql driver with Maven

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jdbc, jar

I tried to use following dependency in Maven:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1200-jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

When I used this driver in the main method, it works, but when I installed the module and tried to run the .jar file, a ClassNotFoundException occurs. What should I do?

I call the driver in the runtime by Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"). I tried to change the scope in dependency to runtime, but it didn't help.

My stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at dbchecker.CountDBChecker.openConnection(CountDBChecker.java:149)
    at dbchecker.CountDBChecker.main(CountDBChecker.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I used the jar by command java -jar and also in iPOJO (like in [this](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo/apache-felix-ipojo-gettingstarted/ipojo-hello-word-maven-based-tutorial.html) tutorial).

I resolved problem with jar executing by maven-assembly-plugin, but I have another connected problem with iPOJO. The jar is not executed by iPOJO and it seems like some instructions in manifest file are missing. Previous manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: dbchecker;uses:="common,checker.service";version="1.0.
 0"
iPOJO-Components: instance { $component="dbchecker.CountDBChecker" }co
 mponent { $name="dbchecker.CountDBChecker" $classname="dbchecker.Coun
 tDBChecker" provides { }manipulation { $classname="dbchecker.CountDBC
 hecker" interface { $name="checker.service.CheckerService" }field { $
 name="connection" $type="java.sql.Connection" }field { $name="dateCol
 umn" $type="java.lang.String" }field { $name="dateFrom" $type="java.l
 ang.String" }field { $name="dateTo" $type="java.lang.String" }field {
  $name="interval" $type="long" }field { $name="maxRequired" $type="lo
 ng" }field { $name="minRequired" $type="long" }field { $name="report"
  $type="common.Report" }field { $name="send" $type="boolean" }field {
  $name="table" $type="java.lang.String" }field { $name="zdegeokodowan
 o" $type="common.Zdegeokodowano" }field { $name="zdegeokodowanoColumn
 " $type="java.lang.String" }method { $name="$init" }method { $name="g
 etInterval" $return="long" }method { $name="check" $return="common.Re
 port" }method { $name="buildCountQuery" $return="java.lang.String" }m
 ethod { $name="executeCountQuery" $return="long" $arguments="{java.la
 ng.String}" $names="{query}" }method { $name="setMessage" $return="ja
 va.lang.String" $arguments="{long,java.lang.String}" $names="{result}
 " }method { $name="setErrorMessage" $return="java.lang.String" $argum
 ents="{long,java.lang.String,long,boolean}" $names="{result,query,req
 uired}" }method { $name="reportErrorMessage" $arguments="{long,java.l
 ang.String,long,boolean}" $names="{result,query,required}" }method { 
 $name="openConnection" $return="java.sql.Connection" }}}
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Built-By: mk
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_79
Tool: Bnd-1.50.0
Bundle-Name: countDBChecker
Bnd-LastModified: 1442913271587
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin & iPOJO 1.12.1
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Import-Package: org.osgi.service.log;version=1.3, common;version="[1.0
 ,2)", org.apache.felix.ipojo.architecture;version="[1.12.1,2.0.0)", c
 hecker.service;version="[1.0,2)", org.apache.felix.ipojo;version="[1.
 12.1,2.0.0)", org.osgi.service.cm;version=1.2
Bundle-SymbolicName: supervisor.countDBChecker
```

Recent manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 24.79-b02 (Oracle Corporation)
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

Should I change the execution goal in my pom.xml? This is the pom (part):

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ipojo-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>ipojo-bundle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: please, add your error stack trace

Comment: Please provide the command you use to start your application and the Manifest file of your application JAR.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your JAR doesn't contain PostgreSQL JDBC driver classes. Just specify classpath to JAR when running your app, e.g.:

```
java -cp postgres-jdbc.jar:myApp.jar mypackage.MyMainClass
```

Or use [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) to build standalone JAR including PostgreSQL dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @a_horse_with_no_name, yep, updated answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

As you running .jar file - dependency libraries should be bringed by yourself (they wouldn't be packed into your jar-file).

So you should provide jar for this dependency in classpath for your running .jar file, ie you should:

- provide correct manifest file with this dependency's jar as part of classpath or provide classpath for dependecy's jar as part of command line
- copy this dependency's jar to target folder